# how to dd sda to an image in a folder in sdc?

Tags: partition, backup

Everywhere I searched, they show commands like this:
`sudo dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c > /PATH/TO/DRIVE/backup_image.img.gz`.

But `sdb` in my case is my Ubuntu startup USB and `sdc` is my external hard disk (the disk I want the backup to be stored). I created a "backups" folder in my external hard disk to store the image of `sda`, and I'm quite sure I should not do `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc/backups/image.img`.

So what would be the right commands to create a gzipped image into the folder on my external hard disk and also the command to restore the image from the image onto `sda`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `sudo dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K`

Don't use `conv=sync,noerror bs=64K`. If there actually is a read error, [dd might corrupt your data](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171) and the backup image will be useless.

If you expect read errors, it's much safer to stick to `ddrescue`. Otherwise just get rid of the `conv=noerror,sync` and if there is an error you'll get a proper error message.

If you must use `dd` this way, then also add `iflag=fullblock`.

> `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc/backups/image.img`

That is a beginner misunderstanding... there is no `/dev/sdc/anything`. The device is `/dev/sdc`, the partition is `/dev/sdc1` (or other number). These are block devices, not directories, so there can't be a subdirectory.

If there is a filesystem on that device, in order to access that filesystem's directory structure and files, you have to mount it first:

```
mkdir /mnt/anywhere
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/anywhere
ddrescue /dev/sda /mnt/anywhere/backup_sda.img /mnt/anywhere/backup_sda.map
```

Example with `sudo dd`, without conv=noerror:

```
sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/sda | gzip > /mnt/anywhere/backup_sda.img.gz
```

The exact command then depends on the location of your mountpoint, replace `/mnt/anywhere` with whatever you chose as a mount location. If it's already mounted somewhere, you can probably see the mountpoint in one of `mount`, `df -h` or `lsblk`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually this was what I was worried about when backing up `sda` to a folder. When `sdc1` is mounted in `/mnt/xyz`, doesn't it become a folder on `sda`? So when `dd` starts making a copy of `sda`, even the `xyz` folder gets gzipped onto itself, probably eventually crashing the disk. Or is Linux smart enough to ignore that mounted folder? I also noticed that the `of=` command wasn't required here.

Comment: If it was like that what would be the point of mounting then? The parent filesystem only has the mountpoint itself (usually an empty directory) and the mountpoint can be changed as you will.